# When find the equation of intersection of plane and sphere

Tags: geometry

When find the equation of intersection of plane and sphere, is below my solution correct?

I found the intersection when I don't know how to parametrize spheres.

(Sorry for bad english)

for example, find $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$ and $x+y+z=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

We can get $z=1-x-y$ from $x+y+z=1$ and Let's set $z=1-x-y=t$

Replace $z$ to $t$, $y$ to $1-x-t$, get $x^{2}+\left(1-x-t\right)^{2}+t^{2}=1$

express that for $x$, $2x^{2}+2\left(t-1\right)x+\left(t-1\right)^{2}+t^{2}-1=0$

Let's solve that equation

$2x^{2}+2\left(t-1\right)x+\left(t-1\right)^{2}-1=2\left(x+\dfrac{t-1}{2}\right)^{2}+\dfrac{\left(t-1\right)^{2}}{2}+t^{2}-1=0$

So $x=-\dfrac{t-1}{2}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{2-2t^{2}-\left(t-1\right)^{2}}}{2}=-\dfrac{t-1}{2}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{1+2t-3t^{2}}}{2}$

So (parametric) equation of the intersection is $x=f\left(t\right),y=1-f\left(t\right)-t,z=t$, where $f\left(t\right)=-\dfrac{t-1}{2}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{1+2t-3t^{2}}}{2}$

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2004224/265466 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit parametrization of a circle is messy (square roots, ± signs and such). It works, like you have shown, but a circle is always easier to parameterize with an angle.

You can find the center by using some properties of spheres and planes (because the sphere is centered, the center of the circle is simply the closest point of the plane to the origin), and using the distance of plane to the origin and some geometry, you get the radius of the circle. All you need are two perpendicular directions on the plane, let's say $(e_x,e_y,e_z)$ and $(f_x,f_y,f_z)$ (let's just normalize them) and you can write

$$x=x_0+r (e_x \cos\phi+ f_x \sin\phi)$$

(and the same for $y$ and $z$). What you see is just the unit circle, parameterized as $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$, oriented along directions $e$ and $f$ instead of $x$ and $y$ axes, stretched by $r$ and moved by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

If you don't use geometric shortcuts, you can write the same as above, with unknown offset, radius and directions $e$ and $f$, plug it in and find the unknown coefficients.

---

Concretely, the plane $x+y+z=1$ has a normal along the vector $(1,1,1)$, meaning the all three coordinates of the center are equal (obviously equal to $1/3$ to satisfy the equation).

The distance of this plane to the origin is $\sqrt{1/3^2+1/3^2+1/3^2}=1/\sqrt{3}$. This distance is one leg of the right angle with hypotenuse 1 (the radius of the sphere) and the other leg $r=\sqrt{1-1/\sqrt{3}^2}=\sqrt{2/3}$.

Now we need two directions perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$. Knowing the properties of the dot product, we can guess $(1,-1,0)$, and then either also guess the other one as $(-1,-1,2)$ (you may know these two from experience for basis vectors in 3D, they turn up in matrices a lot), or get the third one from a cross product $(1,1,1)\times (1,-1,0)$ to ensure them to be perpendicular.

Normalization gives you $\vec{e}=(1,-1,0)/\sqrt{2}$ and $\vec{f}=(-1,-1,2)/\sqrt{6}$.

Note that any other pair of perpendicular vectors on the plane is ok, just puts $\phi=0$ on the different point on the circle and potentially circulate in the opposite direction.

Writing this all out, you get

$$x=\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac23}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\phi-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\sin\phi\right]$$
$$y=\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac23}\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\phi-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\sin\phi\right]$$
$$z=\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\frac23}\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\sin\phi\right]$$

Note: remembering the orthogonal triplet (1,1,1),(1,-1,0),(-1,-1,2) is very useful in general.