# Curve Length Of A Unit Sphere Which Intersect With A Plane

Tags: calculus

Find the curve length of the intersection between the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $x+y=1$

I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004224/parametrization-of-the-intersection-between-a-sphere-and-a-plane) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339243/when-find-the-equation-of-intersection-of-plane-and-sphere?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I still do not manage, I will go [over this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx) I hope it will address the subject.

So we a unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, I know that the parametrization of a sphere is $(r \sin\rho \cos \theta, r\sin \rho \sin \theta, r\cos \rho)$

Now the plane is $x+y=1$ which can be written as $x=1-y$ and to satisfy that the sphere intersect with the plane with need $(1-y)^2+y^2+z^2=1$ which is $1-2y+y^2+y^2+z^2=1$ or $2y(y-1)+z^2=0$

I need to move to the parametrization to find the curve length, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to do any integration.
First of all, you know the curve is a circle, so to find the perimeter, you only need to know the radius.

The idea is that you can find the distance between the plane and the centre of the ball (I will leave it as an exercise). Let me call it $D$. You know that radius of the ball is 1, so the radius of the circle is given by
$$\sqrt{1-D^2}$$
So the curve length is $2\pi \sqrt{1-D^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach. I can think of several, but a geometric approach seems simple.

We know from geometry that the intersection of a sphere with a plane in 3D space is a circle, a point, or empty. We also know that a circle is defined by three distinct points on the circle.

We easily find three points that satisfy both equations: $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $\left(\frac 12,\frac 12,\sqrt{\frac 12}\right)$. This shows that our desired intersection is indeed a circle. But if we know the radius of a circle we can immediately find its arc length, also called its circumference. Now find the center of the circle, then find the radius by calculating the distance from that center to any of the points on the circle, then find the circumference with $C=2\pi r$.

I'll leave that last part to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt2u=x+y,\sqrt v=x-y$ (a rotation by $45°$) and the equations become

$$\begin{cases}u^2+v^2+z^2=1,\\\sqrt2u=1\end{cases}$$ or

$$v^2+z^2=\frac12.$$

This is a circle of radius $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$.